# How to convert negative byte values to mb, gb etc.?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular application I am converting bytes to **MB**, **GB** etc.

I am getting data from backend.
I have for example: All ram, Availble Ram and Used Ram.
All values are stored as long in our case. I am just converting these values.
For "Available Ram" the formula is "AllRam - UsedRam" and getting minus value is considered ok.

But in case of negative values it is not working.

Function I am using is:

```
 const SIZES = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];

 formatBytes(bytes, decimals = 1) {
    for (var i = 0, r = bytes, b = 1024; r > b; i++) r /= b;         
    return `${parseFloat(r.toFixed(decimals))} ${SIZES[i]}`;
  }
```

Tried to add if statement with **bytes < 0** but that didn't help.

Comment: How can you have negative Bytes? Consider using `Math.abs` to keep `bytes` positive?

Comment: I am getting data from backend I have for ex: All ram, Availble Ram and Used Ram. All values storing as long in our case I am just converting this values. For Available ram formula is **AllRam - UsedRam** and getting minus value is ok.

Comment: Would you check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60341978/11299053)? It uses high-order methods rather than `for...` loops and skips zeros after decimal separator, which `.toFixed()` would produce. However, general idea is to use [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) to ignore sign.

Comment: What about using Math.abs, detecting when bytes is negative, do the calculations, and add the negative sign at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) could solve the issue:

```js
const suffixes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
      formatBytes = (n, decimals) => {
        const suffixIndex = suffixes.findIndex((_,i) => Math.abs(n) < 1024**i)-1
        return `${((0|10**decimals*n/1024**suffixIndex)/10**decimals)} ${suffixes[suffixIndex]}`
      }
      
console.log(formatBytes(-38750,2))
```